# Solving $e^{\mathbf a\cdot \nabla}\mathbf r^2 = (\mathbf r+\mathbf a)^2$

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider the scalar field $f(\textbf{r}) = r^2$. Show that, considering some vector $\textbf{a}$, the following is true:

$e^{(\textbf{a} \cdot \nabla)}f(\textbf{r})=f(\textbf{r}+\textbf{a})$

Taking $(\textbf{a} \cdot \nabla)$ to be (by abuse of notation):

$(\textbf{a} \cdot \nabla)=a_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+a_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+a_3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

And **r**, **a** to be vectors given by:

$\textbf{a}=[a_1,a_2,a_3], \textbf{r}=[x,y,z]$

Where all vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am genuinely stumped. Because this is all in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it seems quite straightforward to just explicitly evaluate this. I have reached the following:

$f(\textbf{r}+\textbf{a}) = r^2+a^2+2(r \cdot a)$

$e^{a_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+a_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+a_3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}}(x^2+y^2+x^2)$

And I have no idea where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please give your post a *descriptive title*.

Answer (score 1):

As $D^3 f = 0$, we have that $exp(a \cdot \nabla) f = f + (a\cdot \nabla)f + \frac 12 (a \cdot \nabla)^2 f$.

Now $\nabla f(x) = 2x$, hence $(a \cdot \nabla) f(x) = 2 a \cdot x$, $(a \cdot \nabla)^2 f(x) = 2 a \cdot a$. Therefore $$ [\exp(a \cdot \nabla)f](x) = x \cdot x + 2a \cdot x + a \cdot a = (x+a) \cdot (x+a)$$

Comment: Is it common to write the differential with an uppercase D?

Comment: For the derivative of a function $f \colon U \subseteq X \to Y$, $X$, $Y$ your favorite normed spaces, I learned to write $Df \colon U \to L(X,Y)$, and hence $D^3 f \colon U \to L^3(X;Y)$ for the third derivative. And as far as I am concerned, I would say its quite common.